# Replace Column with single value but LEAVE NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace the entire column with a single value, however, I want to leave the NaNs in place. How do I go about doing that? Lets say for column 'Q1' I would like to replace every value with '1' but leave every row that has NaN in place. In the end, for column 'Q1' every row that has a integer value would now have the integer value '1' and every row that has NaN would still remain as NaN.

```
    Q1  Q2     Q3    Q4

            
0   NaN NaN  1.33   NaN
1   NaN NaN   NaN   1.35
2   0.93 NaN  NaN   NaN
3   NaN 1.08  NaN   NaN
4   NaN NaN  1.28   NaN


...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]:
     Q1   Q2
0   NaN  1.0
1   NaN  2.0
2  0.93  NaN
3   NaN  3.0
4   NaN  4.0

In [14]: df.loc[~df.Q1.isna(), 'Q1'] = 1

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    Q1   Q2
0  NaN  1.0
1  NaN  2.0
2  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  3.0
4  NaN  4.0
```